# SQL Ordering and Selecting One Nearest Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a multiple tables and connecting each tables. Result like that:

```
     CarId   CarLat   CarLon   Path   Minute   Distance
      325    36.000   37.200    H4      74       250
      344    36.050   37.040    H6      75       500
      365    36.300   37.600    H4      76       750
      311    36.060   37.080    H5      77       800
```

As you can see, path have 2 H4, I want to show just smaller minute path. Like this :

```
     CarId   CarLat   CarLon   Path   Minute   Distance
      325    36.000   37.200    H4      74       250
      344    36.050   37.040    H6      75       500
      311    36.060   37.080    H5      77       800
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of SQL SERVER [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to determine this.

So something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY Path ORDER BY Minute) RowID
        FROM    Table
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

MIN minute and GROUP BY

```
SELECT CarId, CarLat, CarLon, Path, MIN(Minute), Distance
FROM table
GROUP BY CarId, CarLat, CarLon, Path, Distance
```